# MySql При записи изменяются слэши

Tags: mysql

У меня есть данные с такими подобного вида `\/dad\/\/ddad` после записи в MySql

становиться вот-так `/dad//ddad` как исправить?

Comment: Экранировать же нужно =)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков А как?

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Всё спасибо, просто сделал вот так \\/dad\\/\\/ddad